# how add PHP Cookies or Sessions on checkbox

Tags: php

my checkbox so I want to add cookies or sessions with php

```
<a title="ON/OFF New Tab">
    <input class="avflipswitch"
           type="checkbox"
           name="openurl"
           value="openmetab"
           onclick="window.location.reload(true);"
           <?php if(isset($_POST['openurl'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>
    />
    <img
        src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Q8V36NYKBH8/XDNyuR1kQbI/AAAAAAAAA1Y/-SC4PKRgT8Yw6wEliFnPi2Ps7_3rYaezQCLcBGAs/s1600/linkinnewtab.png"
        alt="Settings" width="12" height="auto"
    />
</a>
```

with this PHP code I want to set link open _self or _blank

```
<?php 
session_start();
if (isset($_POST["openurl"])) {
   $opurl = "_blank";
} else {
   $opurl = "_self";
};?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a form tag or use javascript to submit a POST.
You can put a label around it and onchange for the input, do a submit.

```
<form method="POST">    
    <label for="openurl">
        <input 
               id="openurl" 
               class="avflipswitch" 
               type="checkbox"
               name="openurl"
               value="openmetab"
               onchange="this.form.submit()"
               <?php if(isset($_POST['openurl'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>
        />
        <img
            src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Q8V36NYKBH8/XDNyuR1kQbI/AAAAAAAAA1Y/-SC4PKRgT8Yw6wEliFnPi2Ps7_3rYaezQCLcBGAs/s1600/linkinnewtab.png"
            alt="Settings" width="12" height="auto"
        />
    </label>
</form>
```

Then in your PHP you can just set the session.

```
<?php 
session_start();
if (isset($_POST["openurl"])) {
   $_SESSION['openurl'] = "_blank";
} else {
   $_SESSION['openurl'] = "_self";
};?>
```